# use classification to improve clustering

Tags: machine-learning

I am from information security field, and have some introductory level understanding of machine learning field. My problem is to identify behavioural patterns from network traffic. If I use supervised learning ( classification ) the results are very promising but I encounter of a problem of missing out a pattern with slight change in behaviour. And If I use clustering then i need to do a much work on manual tuning of centroids position to get better clusters.

I am thinking to ensemble classification and clustering and use classification output to tune cluster centroids. Is this is a good idea to address the problem?

Comment: Are you trying to detect anomalous behavior? It would help if you elaborate what exactly are you trying to achieve here.

Comment: Yes we can say it anomalous, Actually the idea is to capture some specific malware behaviour.

Comment: You should be looking for [Outlier analysis](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/covariance/plot_outlier_detection.html#example-covariance-plot-outlier-detection-py) in that case.

Comment: The question is not about how to find outliers, The question is how to tune outliers detection system performance in terms of detection.

Comment: Would that not translate to using different kernels (linear, rbf, sigmoid) and tuning parameters for one-class SVM? Correct me if I understand this wrongly.

Comment: Yes kernels methods helps in tuning classification, but the problem with malware behavioural detection technique is that these are not adaptable with input data environment. and perform poor if test data is not taken from the same environment which provide training data. this is mainly because of dynamic nature of network traffic.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22019/discussion-between-sidhha-and-nahraf).